# jquery.dragtable.js, simple error, WTF solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

Sorry for bad title, but I'm at a loss here.

I am implementing akottr's dragtable jquery for reordering columns in a table, and have no luck, source code and demos here https://github.com/akottr/dragtable and here http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/

In the source .js file I put,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".reorderable").dragtable();
});
```

And my table has `reorderable` in its class, which should have been all I need

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

on `$(".reorderable").dragtable();` in Chrome dev tools surprise surprise `$(".reorderable").dragtable` returns an undefined

The demo works and is the same source files, am I missing something to register the `dragtable` method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `dragtable` today and got the same error. The error went away when I corrected the order javascript files were loaded and also I used the `dragtable.js` from demo

http://rawgit.com/akottr/dragtable/master/jquery.dragtable.js

its working fine for me. Seems like a very old question,may it help others :)